# how to merge dataframes in a loop in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am facing an issue in my pyspark code.

I have to loop through a timerange and calculate certain metrics for each month in a given timerange and write the result to S3.

Sample code:

```
for date in daterange(startdate, enddate):
   df = spark.read.parquet(PATH + "/" + date)
   df_final = applylogic(df)
```

Problem is, I cant write the dataframe one by one as the S3 path should be overwritten each time. So I need a way to combine the dataframe in the loop into a single dataframe and write the same to S3.

Please help me with a logic for the same in writing the same to S3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do a `union` of the `df_final`s in the for loop:

```
from functools import reduce

df_list = []
for date in daterange(startdate, enddate):
    df = spark.read.parquet(PATH + "/" + date)
    df_final = applylogic(df)
    df_list.append(df_final)
output_df = reduce(lambda x, y: x.union(y), df_list)
```

Comment: Thank you mck, looks like it is working...may  I know how the df_list which is a list got converted to a dataframe here?

Comment: @AswinKs the list of dataframes in `df_list` are unioned together in the last line. The last line is equivalent to `df_list[0].union(df_list[1]).union(df_list[2])...`

Comment: @mick, thanks for the reply. I am facing another issue now. While executing this piece of code, I am getting out of memory error as the code is lazily evaluated and the action is performed only during the reduce operation. I tried to change the code a little bit  by trying to collect the data frame : df_list.append(df_final.collect()) ; but when I do so, the reduce operation is failing with error  -  Attribute Error : list object has no attribute union